# Обход полей структуры в С++

Tags: c++

Вопрос наверное не в рамках правил stackoverflow, но просто интересно, насколько сложно было бы реализовать в компиляторе - методы определение размера структуры в единицах измерения в кол-ве полей структуры и возможность в цикле к ним обращаться ?

Просто в С++ так много всего добавляют последнее время, а это ни как не добавят - как по мне, так полезная бы функция была бы. А может и нет.

Comment: Попытка написать универсальный сериал затор? Посмотрите на это https://youtu.be/jDI5CHKFKd0

Comment: Сделать-то наверное легко, вон, в Clang-е есть `__builtin_dump_struct()`, который печатает произвольные структуры (но доступ к полям не дает). Наверное простой механизм не делают, потому что ждут полноценную рефлексию...

Comment: А может и нет. ... В какой нормальной программе это может понадобится? Думаю ни в какой.

Comment: @KoVadim, очень круто (но я бы, если бы край как понадобилось, специализированный препроцессор написал) . На середине понял, что уже забыл как все начиналось. Реально там прозвучала (хоть и весьма завуалировано) одна в самом деле здравая мысль -- enums -- в практическом программировании эта фича на самом деле вам  не нужна

Comment: @avp, а почему enums на практике не нужна ? Разве оно не предоставляет, так сказать визуальное удобство восприятия кода ?

Comment: Меня смущает обращение в цикле к разнотипным полям в строго типизированном языке.

Comment: @Optimus1, основные проблемы  enums в том, что их нельзя напрямую (на уровне языка) вводить извне и выводить их значения. В общем, они скорее ограничивают ваши возможности, чем спасают от ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут скорее вопрос не в сложности реализации, а в интерфейсе для подобных действий. В целом, при добавлении даже минимального отображения информации о типах во время компиляции язык может даже местами заметно упростится. Например исчезнет необходимость специализации шаблонов из других пространств имен и костылях вроде ADL или макроса `offsetof`. На этот счет выкатывали кучу предложений, которые находятся в разработке, см. [reflection TS](https://github.com/cplusplus/reflection-ts).